# How to set disabled appearance for an Actor

Tags: libgdx

I have a TextButton, and I would like to disable it.
I'm using the default skin.

I have learned that:

- `setDisabled` does nothing
- `setTouchable(Touchable.disabled)` works but does nothing with appearance

I checked the `uiskin.json` file but it only defines `up` and `down` states and nothing about disabled state:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }   
},
```

What should I do? Create a new style and apply it on the button when I disable it? Or is there a built-in state that I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new style or add to one of your existing ones. You can define a background drawable named `disabled` and a font color with `disabledFontColor`. When you omit either of these from your style, then that particular element doesn't change when the you call `setDisabled`.

Comment: Are these names mandatory? Why didn't they put a style in the default skin file?

Comment: They are optional, in that you can leave them out without causing an exception. The "default" style isn't really default, is it? You have to copy and paste it into your project. It is far from a complete skin. A lot of stuff is missing from it.

Comment: If you want to know what you can configure for a certain widget's style, look at that style's Javadoc page or source code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I added two properties into the button's JSON description: `disabledFontColor:red, disabled:default-round-down` and now disabled buttons look different.

Answer (score 0):

- `setDisabled` Does Work!

The reason why you're not noticing a sudden change in appearance is because you have not configured the state of the disabled button within the skin.JSON file or programmatically.

Cobolfoo has created a skin editor for you to use with libGDX. Last commit was 2 years ago but nothing has changed since and the skin-editor should work flawlessly.

[Skin-Editor on github](https://github.com/cobolfoo/gdx-skineditor)

I highly suggest you to take look at it, hence fiddling with skin files is just waste of time imo.

Comment: If only `setDisabled` is used, the click event is still fired, so I had to use `setTouchable`.